# How to implement SignalR if there is more than one iis server?

Tags: signalr

Is there support for a cluster of iis nodes when using SignalR? Or do I need some third party message bus?

Comment: Not an 'answer', more of a hint, hence the comment:

I had been thinking about this as we have a project which may make use of SignalR in such a configuration.
While I haven't actually prototyped anything as yet, it occurred to me that you could probably make use of a distributed object cache such as nCache or AppFabric to look after hubs or at least maintain pools of connections.

Like I said, nothing prototyped but this is the avenue of investigation that I'd start with. I hope it points you in a useful direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet, but they are working on it.

It's planned for the 0.4 release.

When ready, more information will probably be published in the wiki: [SignalR and Webfarms](http://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki) on the wiki

Edit2:

[Azure](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus), [SQL-Server](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-sql-server) and [Redis](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-redis) are implemented.

Answer (score 2):

We just implemented this addon in our application and so far it works flawlessly. It uses a RabbitMq instance to distribute the messages to other servers and is really easy to configure.

https://github.com/mdevilliers/SignalR.RabbitMq

We haven't tried this on a production server yet.